# Relative paths to js files in a parent's sibling folder not reachable through express?

Tags: javascript, express

I've configured express as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/3in1/src/index.html');
});

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/3in1/src/index.html');
});

 /* serves all the static files */
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/3in1/src/'));

 var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
 app.listen(port, function() {
   console.log("Listening on " + port);
 });
```

I have my css in a file under the folder

```
/3in1/src/css/
```

Which all make it to the browser OK.  The problem is when the request is made to my javascript files, which, are located throughout the following folder like so:

```
/3in1/bower_components/library-name/library.js
/3in1/bower_components/library-two/library_two.js
etc...
etc..
etc.
```

**The problem is** I get a 404.  The links in my index look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/PreloadJS/lib/preloadjs-0.4.1.combined.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

What am i doing wrong?  I thought that it would recognize the relative paths I'm using, i.e. "../" but I thought wrong, I guess!  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this simple example was to just add the following line of code:

```
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/3in1/bower_components/'));
```